# How to block a specific user agent in nginx config

Tags: nginx

How do I block a user agent using nginx.
so far I have something like this:

```
if ($http_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; SGH-M919 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.169 Mobile Safari/537.22") {
return 403;}
```

this is from a similar thread on this stack overflow.

I run nginx as a reverse proxy for cherrypy server. I intend to filter a certain user agent using nginx alone but the above code doesn't work on my server.

is that the correct way to do this?
It wasn't included in any block in the nginx config. Should I add it to the "http" block or the "server" block

Comment: where did you try it? you said it didn't work.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the information you seek. Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if the `if` context is inside location or server, so try adding it inside your server block, or inside location if you want the `if` to happen only to specific locations.

Comment: your suggestion worked. putting it inside the "server" block seemed to work and the "if" condition syntax I used was wrong too

Comment: Well glad you figured it out

Answer (score 31, accepted):

in order to block the specific user agent I included this code in the "server" block:

```
if ($http_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; SGH-M919 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.169 Mobile Safari/537.22"){
    return 403;
}
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: Consider returning 444. It's a custom nginx code that drop the connection without responding.

Answer (score 7):

[If's are evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) - use the `map` directive.

> Directive if has problems when used in location context, in some cases
> it doesn’t do what you expect but something completely different
> instead. In some cases it even segfaults. It’s generally a good idea
> to avoid it if possible.

[Nginx Ultimate Bad Bot Blocker](https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/nginx-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker) makes blocking bots easy with support for Debian / Centos / Alpine Linux / FreeBSD.

Comment: Here's a good example of `map`ping: http://ask.xmodulo.com/block-specific-user-agents-nginx-web-server.html

Comment: 1. if's are only evil inside a location context. Not applicable here, this is on the server level. 2. Even if in location context, it is 100% safe to return a 403. So this is clearly a non-evil use of if.

Comment: Introducing a dependency may be quite a bit more evil than carefully using something tricky once in a while. Especially something so huge and sophisticated yet not well known. Those "Easy Configutation Instructions" in 11 steps don't seem easy at all.

Comment: @geira I wonder if these ifs can be used inside the "http" block, instead of the  "server" block, so I could implement these Ifs ( rules ) globally and not host by host

Comment: Please explain some more. How would that look with the user agent above, returning a 403 to those?

Comment: Downvoted because it does not answer the question. Giving a link saying that a tool with a 10-steps install procedure "makes blocking bots easy" is not sufficient.

Comment: @StuartCardall it speaks for itself, not for your answer.

Comment: @bfontaine if Linux is too hard for you - use Windows

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the top of the server:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "SemrushBot|Semrush|AhrefsBot|MJ12bot|YandexBot|YandexImages|MegaIndex.ru|BLEXbot|BLEXBot|ZoominfoBot|YaK|VelenPublicWebCrawler|SentiBot|Vagabondo|SEOkicks|SEOkicks-Robot|mtbot/1.1.0i|SeznamBot|DotBot|Cliqzbot|coccocbot|python|Scrap|SiteCheck-sitecrawl|MauiBot|Java|GumGum|Clickagy|AspiegelBot|Yandex|TkBot|CCBot|Qwantify|MBCrawler|serpstatbot|AwarioSmartBot|Semantici|ScholarBot|proximic|MojeekBot|GrapeshotCrawler|IAScrawler|linkdexbot|contxbot|PlurkBot|PaperLiBot|BomboraBot|Leikibot|weborama-fetcher|NTENTbot|Screaming Frog SEO Spider|admantx-usaspb|Eyeotabot|VoluumDSP-content-bot|SirdataBot|adbeat_bot|TTD-Content|admantx|Nimbostratus-Bot|Mail.RU_Bot|Quantcastboti|Onespot-ScraperBot|Taboolabot|Baidu|Jobboerse|VoilaBot|Sogou|Jyxobot|Exabot|ZGrab|Proximi|Sosospider|Accoona|aiHitBot|Genieo|BecomeBot|ConveraCrawler|NerdyBot|OutclicksBot|findlinks|JikeSpider|Gigabot|CatchBot|Huaweisymantecspider|Offline Explorer|SiteSnagger|TeleportPro|WebCopier|WebReaper|WebStripper|WebZIP|Xaldon_WebSpider|BackDoorBot|AITCSRoboti|Arachnophilia|BackRub|BlowFishi|perl|CherryPicker|CyberSpyder|EmailCollector|Foobot|GetURL|httplib|HTTrack|LinkScan|Openbot|Snooper|SuperBot|URLSpiderPro|MAZBot|EchoboxBot|SerendeputyBot|LivelapBot|linkfluence.com|TweetmemeBot|LinkisBot|CrowdTanglebot") { return 403; }
```

Block more bots