# Why the site give me a 403 forbidden error ? Python/Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I needed to parse a html from a site, if I run on a localhost, the **scrape** works normally, only in the deploy I got an 403 Forbidden and I already tried the user-agent and referer as follow bellow:

Obs: This site and me is from Brazil and my code is deployed with Heroku.

Code:

```
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": 'https://www.guichevirtual.com.br'
    }
url = 'https://www.guichevirtual.com.br/passagem-de-onibus/campo-grande-ms/sao-paulo-todas-sp'
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

output:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

if there is an english error, sorry. I'm learning.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56946001/7903159) suggesting to add more headers?

Comment: Yes, but I did not succeed `'referer': 'https://www.guichevirtual.com.br'`

Comment: did u figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few possibilities that may be in play here:

1. The **site needs more headers** to give you access to a page. I'd suggest taking a look at the [requests headers documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) if you're confused on how to add them, but I see that you already have a `User-Agent` header configured, so it should be fairly easy for you to add more.
2. The **resource you are attempting to access requires that you are logged in, or otherwise authenticated with the page/API**. [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) suggests that you do not have the proper rights to the content. You may need to pass a `X-Username` and `X-Password`/`X-Pin` header in your request, or you may simply be unable to scrape the page.
3. Your useragent **is not an accepted useragent for the site/API.** You may need to change it to something else. Per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144092/how-to-block-a-specific-user-agent-in-nginx-config/43145939) it's fairly simple to block a specific useragent. Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden) which was linked in a comment yet? If not, it might help you.

Comment: 1. I'll take a look about.
2. I don't think so... 'cause when I run on localhost the useragent is `'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1'` and works fine.
3. The useragent that i'm using is the same that works in localhost

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. The only typo in your code is:

```
r = request.get(url, headers=header)
```

is missing an "s"

The correct would be:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

Comment: If I open on localhost works fine too! But in the deploy with Heroku don't work.
Obs: Writing error, in the code is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Heroku is probably hosted outside Brazil. Maybe the site is using a WAF that blocks traffic like that. You may try using a AWS free tier hosted in the US, just to check if it works. Or, a VPN connected to some other country.