# How to block user-agent nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

Access must be denied to the site from the Firefox and Chrome user agents , but if ip adress = 44.221.341.44 and 44.221.342.33 allow and if http-refer = test.com , test.nl , test.de - allow too

i think that to block the agent i have to :

```
    if ($http_user_agent ~ (Firefox|Chrome)) {
        return 403;
    }
```

it works

but I don't know how to allow the necessary IP addresses

so i try

```
if ($remote_addr != XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) {
        set $test A;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~* (python-requests)) {
        set $test "${test}B";
}

if ($test = AB) {
        return 444;
}
```

but how i can add here if http-refer = test.com , test.nl , test.de - allow

Comment: [I think this post will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144092/how-to-block-a-specific-user-agent-in-nginx-config)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/714274/block-an-user-agent-in-nginx-except-those-coming-from-a-specific-ip)

Comment: thank you, this is already half the task